# Access 'Not Equal To' Join

Tags: join, equals, ms-access-2013

I have two tables, neither with a primary id.  The same combination of fields uniquely identifies the records in each and makes the records between the two tables relate-able (I think).

I need a query to combine all the records from one table and only the records from the second not already included from the first table.  How do I do this using 'not equal to' joins on multiple fields?  My results so far only give me the records of the first table, or no records at all.

Comment: Please post your queries that you mention showing only results from the first table or no records at all.

Comment: Here is a try at a query, but it produces no records....

Comment: SELECT ECDSlides.[Supplier Code], ECDSlides.[Supplier Name], ECDSlides.Commodity

FROM ECDSlides LEFT JOIN (ECDSlides.Commodity = [Mit Task Details2].Commodity) AND (ECDSlides.[Supplier Code] = [Mit Task Details2].[Supplier Code])

WHERE (((ECDSlides.[Supplier Code])<>[Mit Task Details2].[Supplier Code]) AND ((ECDSlides.Commodity)<>[Mit Task Details2].[Commodity]) AND ((ECDSlides.[Baseline ECD])<>[Mit Task Details2].[Baseline ECD]));

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987844/ms-access-query-to-display-rows-of-table1-which-are-not-in-table2-using-two-fiel?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

```
SELECT fieldA,fieldB FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT fieldA,fieldB FROM tableB
```

Union should remove automatically. 'Union All' would not.

If, for some reason, you get perfect duplicates and they are not removed, you could try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
    SELECT fieldA,fieldB FROM tableA
    UNION
    SELECT fieldA,fieldB FROM tableB
) AS subquery
```

Comment: Union won't work - it will duplicate values of tableA.  TableA is a sub-set of TableB, with an additional identifying field attached.

Comment: Are you sure, did you try? "Union will remove duplicates. Union All does not." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127714/remove-duplicates-from-sql-union

Comment: Perfect!  I did not know the distinction between Union and Union All.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT ECDSlides.[Supplier Code], ECDSlides.[Supplier Name], ECDSlides.Commodity 

FROM ECDSlides LEFT JOIN (ECDSlides.Commodity = [Mit Task Details2].Commodity) AND (ECDSlides.[Supplier Code] = [Mit Task Details2].[Supplier Code]) 

WHERE [Mit Task Details2].Commodity Is Null;
```